# How to escape asterisk and question mark using RLIKE in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a query to search posts by content. I'm still using mysql 5.5 with innoDB so `RLIKE` seems to be one of the only choices:

```
$sql = "SELECT title,content FROM table1 WHERE content RLIKE ?";
$i = 1;
$users = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$users->bindValue($i++, $purifier->purify($_GET['content']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$users->execute();
```

But I found that when I enter asterisk or a question mark as a parameter value (e.g www.site.com?content=*), I'm getting

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
1139 Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp.
```

How can I avoid this error? Are `*` and `?` the only two special characters that would cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rlike requires a valid regular expression as operand. That means that 'Yes, there are other characters than `*` and `?` that will cause an error.'

How to avoid? It depends on what you want to achieve exactly. The easiest would be to avoid regular expressions altogether. If you need that the user can enter any regular expression, the best way to validate it would be to use it in a query and catch the error if it is malformed.

If you want only to find content that contains the string, using `like` is much more reliable. And you need to escape only `%` and `_`.

```
$search = '%'.str_replace(array('%',  '_'), array('\%', '\_'), $_GET['content']).'%';
$sql = "SELECT title,content FROM table1 WHERE content LIKE ?";
...
```